# Change order of reading strings perl

Tags: perl

I have to read strings from a file, split them into two-character chunks and write it into another file.

I have written the below snippet which works but I need to change the order of the input strings. For example if there are nine strings I need to read it like 2, 8, 4, 5, 7, 6, 3, 1, 9 or something like that

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;    #So I dont have to worry about my file

open( my $fh,  "<", "dataFile.txt" );
open( my $fh1, '>', 'report.txt' );



while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    chomp $line;

    my @line_array = split( /\s+/, $line );
       for ( unpack( "(A2)*", $line ) ) {
        print "$_\n";
        print $fh1 "$_\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Some example input and output data would help a lot

Comment: There's a lot of junk code in that sample. You never use `@file_array`, `@line_array`, `$dir` or `$name` after assigning them. Is there a reason for them to be there?

Comment: Load the lines into an array. Permutate the array as you like and iterate over these reordered strings. You need to use two while loops. The first for reading the lines intio an array, the second to iterate over the array.

Comment: You can permutate the strings by creating a permutation vector into an array. `my @perm_array = [1, 7, 3, 4, 6, 5, 2, 0, 8]` be sure to start with index 0 because perl arrays use zero based indexes. In order to get the 4th string to splitt and write, use `$string_array[$perm_array[3]]`.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer: Computers are pretty good at subtracting one, so if it's more natural to specify the indexes with a base of 1 then you should do so and let the code take care of the rest. See the `map` in my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to work out what your data may look like from the code you've already written

Does this help? It splits each eighteen-character line into nine character pairs and shuffles them according to the order you have in your question before printing them

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

#open my $fh,  '<', dataFile.txt'
open my $fh1, '>', 'report.txt';

my $fh = \*DATA;

use constant FIELD_ORDER => ( 2, 8, 4, 5, 7, 6, 3, 1, 9 );

while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    chomp $line;

    my @pairs = unpack '(A2)*', $line;

    print $fh1 "$_\n" for @pairs[ map {$_-1} FIELD_ORDER ];
}

__DATA__
112233445566778899
```

#### output

```
22
88
44
55
77
66
33
11
99
```

Comment: Thank you ! It seems to work. But why is my question being down voted ?

Comment: @user2017810 Votes are private so I can only speculate, but I would guess that you got downvotes because 1) before Borodin edited your question, your code had zero indentation and the final two curly braces weren't formatted as code 2) before Borodin edited, your description of the problem was hard to understand 3) you didn't show what your input data looks like 4) you didn't specify what the exact ordering should be ("3, 1, 2 or something like that" is a bit vague). The moral of the story is that you should always format your posts properly and make sure they're as clear as possible.

Comment: @user2017810: I would add to that that I needed to point out that there were apparently junk statements in your code. You seem to have edited your question in response to that (and you should really have left a comment) but have left the code badly-formatted again and still with an assignment to `my @line_array`, which is one of the things that I mentioned in my original note. You have also left the code badly formatted again, and I didn't think I should tidy it a second time. Programming is an *extremely precise* profession, and you must take a great deal more care with what you write

Comment: @Borodin Thanks for the feedback ! I will try to format my code in a better way next time !